# Flat promise chain series with each promise call dependent upon resolution of prior call

Tags: javascript, promise

What is the recommended method to flatten out a promise series so that subsequent promises are not run if the preceding promise does not resolve without nesting inside of the initial promises then statement?

I don't want to run promise 2 if promise 1 does not resolve.

```
var promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  reject('catch 1')
});

var promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  resolve('pass 2')
});
```

I want to do this:

```
var p1Resolved = promise1.then(result=>{
   handleResult(result);
})
.catch(error => {
   handleError(error);
})

if(p1Resolved) 
{
    promise2.then(result=>{
       handleResult(result);
    })
   .catch(error => {
      handleError(error);
   })
}
```

I don't want to do this  (nest promise2 inside of promise1 then):

```
promise1.then(result=>{
   promise2.then(result=>{
       handleResult(result);
    })
   .catch(error => {
      handleError(error);
   })
})
.catch(error => {
   handleError(error);
})
```

Comment: In all your examples, you're **always** running `promise2`. Can you explain why you don't want to nest the promises?

Comment: Turn it to a function and call when necessary? `var promise2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  resolve('pass 2')
});`

Comment: For first comment, I'd prefer to write flat statements when possible and want to find out if there is a pattern of doing this. For second comment, I'm not sure how wrapping in a function provides a flat pattern where 2 doesnt run unless 1 is resolved and 2 isnt nested in 1. Can you post a working example with the pattern I've requested? Thanks.

Comment: Use a library like $q,  async or bluebird promise to handle your promises.  Its pretty easy and do what you want

Comment: Is there a method of doing this without a library just with some promise chaining syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn promise2 into a function (may as well do promise1 as well, for consistency)

```js
var promise1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('catch 1'));
var promise2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('pass 2'));

promise1()
.then(result => promise2())
.then(result => console.log('done'))
.catch(reason => console.log('error', reason));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the pattern I was looking for.